# Onboarding openapi to Kong deployed on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openapi, kong, insomnia, kong-ingress

Onboarding open api yaml into Kong.
I need to figure out a way to configure my openapi yaml(declarative config yaml generated via insomnia) to Kong(OSS version) that is deployed on K8s.

I have a simple open api yaml (generated using insomnia)
which has to be configured to Kong(OSS) that is deployed in kubernetes cluster.
How do I deploy this open API yaml as a service/deployment onto K8s ?
Should I containerize my open api yaml and then pull the image in the deployment yaml? Or is there any other way I can proceed ahead?
I am new to this Kong api management tool and couldn't really find a precise solution as to how I should proceed ahead.

If at all I need to use decK cli,should I deploy decK cli onto same cluster ?or do I have an alternative?

Would be really helpful if someone can guide me here.Thank you.